# Перебор списка Python

Tags: python, списки, вывод

q, я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но опять возникла похожая проблема.
Имею вот такой код:

```
input_text = str(input('Введите ваш текст: '))
list1 = ['3','10','2']
list2 = ['а', 'б', 'в']
vivod = []

for c in input_text:
    if c in list1:
        i = list1.index(c)
        vivod.append(list2[i])

print(' '.join(vivod))
```

Код просит ввести пользователя число и когда он вводит например 3 ищет это в первом списке и выводит этот индекс со второго, но если ввести двухзначное число, например 10 в консоль выведет ошибку или если во  списке найдет число 1 выведет его индекс в ответ. Мне нужно чтобы ( на примере этого кода ) при ввода 10 выводило его индекс со второго, а не индекс 1.

P'S

Извините за ошибки и не нормально поставленного вопроса, прошу не пинать ногами.

Comment: А в чём смысл цикла `for c in input_text`?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так...

```
list1 = ['3','10','2']
list2 = ['а', 'б', 'в']
vivod = []

input_text = [str(x) for x in input('Введите ваш текст: ').split()]

for data in input_text:
    if data in list1:
        vivod.append(list2[list1.index(data)])

print(' '.join(vivod))
```

Comment: Если нужно ввести несколько символов за раз ?

Comment: Исправил. Теперь можно вводить несколько значений через пробел, если нужен другой разделитель, то, замените его в методе split(). Надеюсь я правильно понял, что именно вам надо. :)

Answer (score 0):

Просто решение в более пайтоновском стиле :)

```
input_text = str(input('Введите ваш текст: '))
list1 = ['3','10','2']
list2 = ['а', 'б', 'в']

s_dic = dict(zip(list1, list2))

vivod = [s_dic[str] for str in input_text.split(" ") if str in s_dic]

print(' '.join(vivod))
```